# JLS 8 regarding keyword super and protected members

Tags: java, super, jls

In JLS 8 [15.11.2-1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#d5e24643) (page 505), I cannot understand what they mean by:

> Note that `super.x` is not specified in terms of a cast, due to difficulties around access to `protected` members of the superclass.

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider this:

```
public class T2 {
    protected int x = 2;
}

/* in a different package */
public class T3 extends T2 {
    int x = 3;
    void test() {
        System.out.println(this.x); // prints 3
        System.out.println(super.x); // prints 2

        T2 this_as_t2 = (T2)this;
        System.out.println(this_as_t2.x); // Error: Can't access protected member x of class T2

        System.out.println(((T2)this).x); // Same error as above
    }
}
```

If `super.x` was equivalent to `((T2)this).x`, then you wouldn't be able to use `super.x` to refer to the `x` field in `T2`.

So the specification does *not* say they're equivalent (because they aren't always). However, they're still equivalent in some situations - such as if both classes are in the same package, or if the field is `public`.